# Making nested Function calls within Haskell

Tags: haskell

Working on converting over some scheme code to haskell for some practice and I have a bit of an issue with creating a custom Binary Search Tree.
`node x l r` returns a lambda that gets you the corresponding value of that tree. However, when creating `let t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)` I get the following errors:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( binTree.hs, binTree.o )

binTree.hs:29:18: error:
    • No instance for (Eq ((a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0))
        arising from a use of ‘node’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)
      In an equation for ‘t1’:
          t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)
      In the expression:
        do { let t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0);
             print $ size t1 }

binTree.hs:29:23: error:
    • No instance for (Num (a1 -> a0 -> t0))
        arising from the literal ‘5’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the first argument of ‘node’, namely ‘5’
      In the expression: node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)
      In an equation for ‘t1’:
          t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)

binTree.hs:29:26: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a1’ arising from a use of ‘node’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a1)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        t1 :: ((a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0
          (bound at binTree.hs:29:13)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a1’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus three instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 3 0 0)’
      In the expression: node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)
      In an equation for ‘t1’:
          t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)

binTree.hs:29:31: error:
    • No instance for (Num (a0 -> t0)) arising from the literal ‘3’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the first argument of ‘node’, namely ‘3’
      In the second argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 3 0 0)’
      In the expression: node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)

binTree.hs:29:47: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘node’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        t1 :: ((a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0
          (bound at binTree.hs:29:13)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus three instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 7 0 0)’
      In the third argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)’
      In the expression: node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)

binTree.hs:29:52: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘7’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        t1 :: ((a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0
          (bound at binTree.hs:29:13)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘node’, namely ‘7’
      In the second argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 7 0 0)’
      In the third argument of ‘node’, namely ‘(node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)’

binTree.hs:30:17: error:
    • No instance for (Num ((a1 -> a0 -> t0) -> a1 -> a0 -> t0))
        arising from a use of ‘size’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘size t1’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ size t1
      In the expression:
        do { let t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0);
             print $ size t1 }
```

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}                                                                                                                
node x l r = \s ->                                                                                                                               
        if s == 0                                                                                                                                
            then x                                                                                                                               
        else if s == 1                                                                                                                           
            then l                                                                                                                               
        else if s == 2                                                                                                                           
            then r                                                                                                                               
        else error "invalid value"                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                 
--search x t = do                                                                                                                                
--  not (null t) && ((x == (datr t)) || ((x < (datr t)) && (search x (left t))) || ((x > (datr t)) && (search x (right t))))                     
                                                                                                                                                 
multiply tree = do                                                                                                                               
    if tree == 0                                                                                                                                 
        then 1                                                                                                                                   
    else ($ datr tree) * (multiply ($ left tree)) * (multiply ($ right tree))                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                 
datr t = t 0                                                                                                                                     
left t = t 1                                                                                                                                     
right t = t 2                                                                                                                                    
size t = do                                                                                                                                      
    if t == 0                                                                                                                                    
        then 0                                                                                                                                   
    else 1 + (size ($ left t)) + (size ($ right t))                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                 
main :: IO ()                                                                                                                                    
main = do                                                                                                                                        
    let t1 = node 5 (node 3 0 0) (node 8 (node 7 0 0) 0)                                                                                         
    print $ size t1
```

Original working scheme code:

```lisp
(define (node x l r)   ; x is data, l is left, r is right
  (lambda (s)
    (cond  ((= s 0) x)
           ((= s 1) l)
           ((= s 2) r)
           (#t 'error))))

(define (search x t)   ; assuming a binary search tree
  (and (not (null? t))
       (or (= x (data t))
           (and (< x (data t)) (search x (left t)))
       (and (> x (data t)) (search x (right t))))))

(define (multiply tree)
  (if (null? tree) 1 (* (data tree) (multiply (left tree)) (multiply (right tree)))))
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
(define (howmany tree expr)
  (if (null? tree) 0
  (if (expr (data tree)) (+ 1 (howmany (left tree) expr) (howmany (right tree) expr)) 
  (+ (howmany (left tree) expr) (howmany (right tree) expr)))))
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
(define (data t) (t 0))
(define (left t) (t 1))
(define (right t) (t 2))
(define (size t) (if (null? t) 0 (+ 1 (size (left t)) (size (right t)))))
(define t1 (node 5 (node 3 '() '()) (node 8 (node 7 '() '()) '())))
(display (multiply t1))
(display "\n")
```

Comment: Please consider adding type signatures to all your definitions. This will give you much more useful error messages.

Comment: What do you think the `($ foo bar)` syntax means?

Comment: Unlike Scheme, Haskell is typed, preventing you to store arbitrary data in your tree. More in detail, it looks like a node in your tree can be either a leaf-number `0` or a subtree `node x l r` which is a function. Since they must be of the same type, Haskell is trying to use `0` as a function, and this will create issues. The idiomatic solution is to use algebraic types (`data`). If you really want to stick to Church encodings, you will instead need to use polymorphic types, but this is more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the scheme the symbol `node` represents a constructor of a node of a binary tree where the first value is the nodes data, then the left sub tree, then the right.  Similarly, `datr`, `left`, and `right` are projection functions that allow you to access fields of the tree.

Haskell has syntax for data declarations.  In the case of such a Tree it would look like so:

```
data Tree                                                                                                
    = Node { datr :: Integer, left :: Tree, right :: Tree }                                                         
    | Empty
```

From here you can define multiply by pattern matching against either a node of a tree (`Node`) or the empty tree (`Empty`):

```
multiply :: Tree -> Integer
multiply Empty = 1
multiply (Node x l r) = x * (multiply l) * (multiply r)
```

The first line is a type signature.  Haskell is statically typed and you are encouraged to explicitly provide the type.  Not doing so makes the code and any error messages harder to read.

The second line matches against the case when the tree is empty, much like the Scheme `null?` test case.  Then in the third line we get to the recursive calls for the sub-trees.

What's shown with `multiple` is idiomatic Haskell code.  A more direct translation would be:

```
multiply t =
    if t == Empty
        then 1
        else datr t * left t * right t
```

While functional, this sort of code is discouraged - equality tests carry more restrictions and machinery than pattern matching.  The functions of `datr`, `left`, and `right` are partial so if they are applied to a value such as `Empty` they will fail (i.e. if the preceding logic doesn't hold the invariants you intended); pattern matches have no such failure case.

I'll leave the remaining functions as an exercise.

Comment: I haven't dealt with `data` like that, so I changed `t1` to:
`t1 :: Tree`
`let t1 = Node 5 (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 8 (Node 7 Empty Empty) Empty)`
what am I missing?